# Sending a Text from JTextfield to another Jtextfield using the enter button

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVXy7.png)

What i need is to be able to create this box. What I need is for the text to be entered into the first box on the right, and once the enter button is pressed, the text on the right goes to the text on the left. The left text box should not be editable. I am not a very skilled programmer, but the following is what I have so far. Any and all help is appreciated.

```
//file: GridBag3.java
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    public class GridBag3 extends JPanel {
          GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
          JTextField enterText = new JTextField ("Type a word you remember and press ENTER");
          JTextField recieveText = new JTextField("Recieve Text");
    
      public GridBag3() {
          GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        constraints.weightx = 3.0;
        constraints.weighty = 3.0;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        int x, y;  // for clarity
        constraints.gridheight = 2; // span two rows
        addGB(recieveText,   x =2, y = 1);
        constraints.gridheight = 2; // set it back
        addGB(enterText,   x = 0, y = 1);
        constraints.gridwidth = 1; // span two columns
        addGB(new JLabel("Recall"),  x = 1, y = 0);
        constraints.gridwidth = 2; // set it back
        addGB(new JLabel(""), x = 0, y = 0);
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        addGB(new JLabel(""), x = 2, y =0);
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        addGB(new JLabel(""), x = 2, y = 2);
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        addGB (new JLabel(""), x = 0, y =2);
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        
        } 

      void addGB(Component component, int x, int y) {
        constraints.gridx = x;
        constraints.gridy = y;
        add(component, constraints);
      }
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
      { 
              
     enterText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          recieveText.requestFocusInWindow();    
        }
    }); 
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBag3");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocation(200, 200);
        frame.setContentPane(new GridBag3());
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should first read the following tutorial? [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

Comment: When I ran the code in your question, it produced [this](https://imgur.com/32eZX4w)

Comment: Yes that is correct, I just cannot figure out how to do the entering into a Jtextfield and then getting it to go to the other

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to declare a String field, this way you could store the Text entered in your input field into that field to access it later.

Inside your Constructor, declare the String, something like:

```
private String savedText = "";
```

Since you are getting your input from a textfield already containing characters, something like "Enter text here", good practice would be to clear it before the user can input anything. This way only what is entered in the textfield will be stored in your String variable.

-First, you need to clear your textfield when the user clicks in it so you use a mouseListener(mouseReleased or mouseClicked).

```
textField.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        super.mouseReleased(e);
        // set the textfield to empty String
        textField.setText(" ");
    }
});
```

Second, you set your actionListener (Enter key pressed inside textfield), something like you did:

```
textfield.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Input action to be done here
        }
    }
});
```

Then you can do some data validation before saving the String, just to make sure the user actually input something by using an if statement, something like this:

```
if(!userInput.getText().equals(" ")) { // get the text from the textfield, 
check if it's empty
            //Do something
        }
```

Inside you IF statement, you save the text from your textfield into your String variable, then set the text of your other component to that variable.

```
savedText = textField.getText(); // Set your String variable to the text in 
the textField
label1.setText(savedText); // Set the text of your other component
```

I made this real quick so forgive the look or any issues in functionality, the goal here is just to show the logic of listeners. I use Intellij so My Constructor will differ from yours if you use NetBeans or Eclipse, but the principles remain the same.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

/**
 * @author ADsquared on 2020-10-22.
 * @project Stack
 */
public class Recall {

private JPanel root;
private JTextField userInput;
private JLabel recallText;
private String saveText = " ";


public Recall() {

    userInput.setText("Enter text to send");
    userInput.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseReleased(e);
            userInput.setText(" ");
        }
    });
    userInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(!userInput.getText().equals(" ")) {
                saveText = userInput.getText();
                recallText.setText(saveText);
            }
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Recall");
    frame.setContentPane(new Recall().root);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```