# Can someone tell me why my program isnt running?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtextfield, gridbaglayout

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 
 public class RecallStudy extends JFrame
        implements KeyListener, 
            ActionListener
 {
    
    //CREATION OF ELEMENTS
     JLabel recallLabel;
     JTextField enterText;
     String enterTex;
     JTextField recieveText;
     JPanel displayInfo;
     GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
     
     
     public static void main (String [] args) {
         //MAKING THE WINDOW
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("RecallStudy");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            frame.setLocation(200, 200);
            frame.setContentPane(new RecallStudy());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
    
}
     //GRIDLAYOUT CONSTRUCTION
        public RecallStudy() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            constraints.weightx = 3.0;
            constraints.weighty = 3.0;
            constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            int x, y; // for clarity
            constraints.gridheight = 2; // span two rows
            addGB(recieveText,   x =2, y = 1);
            constraints.gridheight = 2; // set it back
            addGB(enterText,   x = 0, y = 1);
            constraints.gridwidth = 1; // span two columns
            addGB(new JLabel("Recall"),  x = 1, y = 0);
            constraints.gridwidth = 2; // set it back
            addGB(new JLabel(""), x = 0, y = 0);
            constraints.gridwidth = 1;
            addGB(new JLabel(""), x = 2, y =0);
            constraints.gridwidth = 1;
            addGB(new JLabel(""), x = 2, y = 2);
            constraints.gridwidth = 1;
            addGB (new JLabel(""), x = 0, y =2);
            constraints.gridwidth = 1;
            
       //Set the proper restrictions on the listeners
            enterText.addKeyListener(this);
            recieveText.setEditable(false);
        }

          void addGB(Component component, int x, int y) {
            constraints.gridx = x;
            constraints.gridy = y;
            add(component, constraints);
          }
          public RecallStudy(String name) {
              super (name);
          }
      
          public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
              displayInfo(e, "KEY TYPED: ");
          }
          
          /** Handle the key pressed event from the text field. */
          public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
              displayInfo(e, "KEY PRESSED: ");
          }
          
          /** Handle the key released event from the text field. */
          public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
              displayInfo(e, "KEY RELEASED: ");
          }
          
          /** Handle the button click. */
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              //Clear the text components.
              enterText.setText("");
              recieveText.setText(enterTex);
              
              //Return the focus to the typing area.
              enterText.requestFocusInWindow();
          }
         private void displayInfo (KeyEvent e, String keyStatus) {
             
         }

}
```

For some reason, this code is not running...I cannot understand why...can someone please explain? I do not get any errors on my code when I just have it down, but the second I try to run it it does not work. I am confused as to what components I am missing to make it run. I know that I have not finished the displayInfo section, but that does not seem to be the reason why it won't run. I am just really confused, I feel like I started this code the same way I do every other but this one just won't run.

Comment: This appears to me to be a continuation of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64433071/sending-a-text-from-jtextfield-to-another-jtextfield-using-the-enter-button#comment113934347_64433071). It looks like you have made some improvements on the code in that question and rather than [edit] that question, you decided to post another question. Your code gives me the impression that you need to thoroughly learn _Swing_ and that is not something you can do via questions on SO. Note that the value for `weightx` must be between `0.0` and `1.0` and not `3.0`.

Comment: On at least two of your questions related to Java & Swing, neither tag was added. To get the best 'coverage' to the people who might be able to help, don't forget to add these tags! (E.G. I tune in only to the [tag:swing] tag these days). The only reason I saw this is that occasionally I pick out a tag (like [tag:jframe]) and look for posts that lack the Swing tag.

Comment: See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Answer (score 1):

For starters:

```
JTextField recieveText; // declares the field, but does not create it!
```

So it should be:

```
JTextField recieveText = new JTextField("No NullPointerException!");
```

Then:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("RecallStudy");
// ..
frame.setContentPane(new RecallStudy());
```

Should be something like:

```
JFrame frame = new RecallStudy();
// ..
frame.setTitle("RecallStudy");
```

But honestly, that code is riddled with 'errors'. It'd be better to toss it out and start again after going through the Swing trail of the tutorial.

> but that does not seem to be the reason why it won't run

Always copy/paste error and exception output!